# How to set up gRPC client - server correctly

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a **gRPC** client and a server, when I run them they seem to be running fine, but when I try to dial a server with a client I get an error:

```
"Error": {
    "code": 14,
    "message": "all SubConns are in TransientFailure"
},
```

No idea what is it. I tried to find a solution with google, no success there.

Any ideas? Here is my server code:

```
lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", cfg.Host, cfg.Port))
if err != nil {
    logger.Critical(ctx, "failed to listen: %v", err)
} else {
    logger.Info(ctx, "[userserver] running at %s:%d", cfg.Host, cfg.Port)
}

grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
userServer := userserver.New()
pb.RegisterDomainServer(grpcServer, userServer)
rpcErr := grpcServer.Serve(lis)

if rpcErr != nil {
    logger.Critical(ctx, "failed to serve: %v", rpcErr)
}
```

btw the server here shows log:

> 2018/02/08 07:03:37.603287 INFO:  [userserver] running at localhost:3001

and client:

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial(c.serverAddr, grpc.WithInsecure())
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer conn.Close()

client := pb.NewDomainClient(conn)
_, err = client.Dispatch(ctx, &pb.Command{
    Name:    command,
    Payload: payload,
})
```

and this is port buff

```
service Domain {
  rpc Dispatch(Command) returns (Response);
}

message Command {
  string name = 1;
  bytes payload = 2;
}

message Response {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the server listening to that port?

```
// Most linux 
lsof -i :3001

// OSX
lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P
```

Are you connecting the client to the right address?

c.serverAddr should be "127.0.0.1:3001"

Comment: I am running this on a docker image `golang:latest`  so `lsof`, `netstat`, `nmap` gives **command not found**

Comment: if it helps here is my [docker-compose](https://github.com/vardius/go-api-boilerplate/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) set-up

Comment: looks like the docker manifest is not correct (the port section for the services)

Answer (score 0):

> This error means the connection to your server is down for some reason.

You're printing that your server is running at localhost:3001, but don't check whether the server has any errors serving on that address.

Replace your last line in the server with:

```
if err := grpcServer.Serve(lis); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
}
```

Also where does the context `ctx` in the server startup come from?

---

I'm assuming your proto definition looks something like that - otherwise there might be other issues:

```
package ...;

service Domain {
   rpc Dispatch(Command) returns (...) {}
}

message Command {
   ... Name
   ... Payload    
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question with proto definitions, unfortunetelly `grpcServer.Serve` does not return error

Comment: and the context is assigned like `ctx := context.Bacground()`